# I cant load the image in image viewer

Tags: codenameone, image-viewer

When I use the image viewer, it didn't work. I add the image viewer component in a container, then in properties tab -> image, I add the image. Then I run the app, it showed "an internal application error occurred: java.lang.nullpointerexception". Do I need to write any code and how, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Place the stack trace of the exception and the code that was generated for that pointing to the specific line that triggered it. Also make sure that you're using version 6.2 of the GUI builder.